# Node-fetch: Disable SSL verification

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I have the following code, which is run from a express server:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let formBody = [];

const dataLogin = {
      'username': 'myUser',
      'password': 'myPassword'
};

for (let p in dataLogin) {
   let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(p);
   let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataLogin[p]);
   formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
 }

 formBody = formBody.join("&");   

 const url = 'https://external-login-api.com';
 return fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Content-Length': formBody.length         
  },     
  body: formBody
 });
```

When I run the code I get the following error, despite being able to run the request in Postman with no problems.

> {"message":"request to https://external-login-api.com failed, reason: write EPROTO 7316:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:openssl\ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:1472:\n","type":"system","errno":"EPROTO","code":"EPROTO"}

How do I disable SSL verification for this request?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Will ensure you ignore any rejected TLS certificates, or you can set this as an environment variable when running your node service. **However this will likely not help, and is probably a bad idea.** The SSL error is not because the certificate is invalid (such as a self signed certificate) but instead because of a weak Diffie-Hellman key in the SSL/TLS configuration.

If this a service you're hosting you should look at correcting and improving your TLS/SSL cyphers. [See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706878/2265722).

The important part is:

> You should use 2048-bit Diffie-Hellman groups or larger. You should
>   not be using 512-bit or 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman groups.

If this is a third party service, you should consider contacting them or using a different service as they are leaving themselves open to the [Logjam attack](https://weakdh.org/) which is also discussed in the answer linked above.

Comment: I'm on a corporate network and almost everything is blocked. This answer saved my life.

Comment: @DanielCarpioContreras I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Had to set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to zero from powershell before running tests for the flag to take effect. Testing against .Net Core in localhost I was following the [.Net Core instructions to set dev certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#with-dotnet-dev-certs).

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn Does the env parameter option work for the built-in `fetch` in Node v18? I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @OldGeezer I've not really touched nodejs for a few years now but I got curious so went looking. Fetch in node v18 is handled by the undici module which is now being bundled into the nodejs core. It's a full rewrite of http handling as far as I can tell. As a result it doesn't use the old node tls stack and so you need to pass it in separately. The docs for disabling tls verification are here: https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/best-practices/client-certificate.

Comment: @OldGeezer actually, looking into it a bit more that seems to only be about authentication of client provided certificates by a server. I'm unsure how undici handles the reverse (what this question is looking at). I'm afraid I've reached the end of my very rusty nodejs knowledge here. Hopefully that gives you a place to look for more answers though.

Comment: @OldGeezer Yes, this works for Node v18 built-in fetch. The `rejectUnauthorized` option does not currently work me, possibly because I'm doing a `setGlobalDispatcher()` to a `ProxyAgent` instance (imported `from "undici"`), and it might not support that option.

Comment: this is great, but makes things insecure (e.g. man in the middle attacks).  how do i get fetch to allow the corporate cert i want it to accept ? what does fetch actually read to verify ca-certificates ??

Comment: @Moe Singh Yes you're right, this is not secure but is what the original question was asking for. In your case, you'll need to extend the well known root certificates with your own. You can do this via the nodejs environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_extra_ca_certsfile. There are lots of other questions on stackoverflow which explain how it works if you need extra help.

Answer (score 117):

The other way to do is to set your own agent to the fetch call.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const https = require('https');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });

const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
      agent: httpsAgent,
    });
```

Comment: This is a better approach (if what you want is to Disable SSL verification for node-fetch) since it only limits the ban-lift to the case you need it (like a one off internal query), while still validating the certs of other connections (like third party services)

Comment: I was just running a one-off script against my https localhost server and this was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't work for node18 with build-it fetch

Comment: Works like charm with node 8.x and pm2@2.6.0  for those who are for some reason stuck on node v8.x

Comment: doesn't work for node 20 with built-in fetch